# Intersection of 2 Linestrings (not interpolated)

Tags: postgis, sql, intersection

I am struggling with a query in POSTGIS

I want to find linestring geometries where the geometries are containing the same point.

I don't want to calculate the intersection points. I only want to get a point, if the point is a real member of both geometries.

Example

> SELECT ST_AsText(ST_Function(ST_GeomFromText('LINESTRING(1 2, 2 2, 0 0)'),
>           ST_GeomFromText('LINESTRING(0 1, 2 2, 3 0)') ) )

should return

> POINT(2 2)

and

> SELECT ST_AsText(ST_Function(ST_GeomFromText('LINESTRING(1 2, 10 10)'),
>           ST_GeomFromText('LINESTRING(1 1, 2 2, 3 3)') ) )

should return

> EMPTY

or something similiar for empty.

How can I achieve that in a single query?

I tried to use ST_Intersection(), but this one calculates the point (which is wrong to my requirements).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a query that returns vertices which are common for your input linestrings:

```
select ST_AsText(ST_Intersection(subq.g1,subq.g2)) from 
(select ST_Collect(dump1.geom) as g1, ST_Collect(dump2.geom) as g2 from ST_DumpPoints(ST_GeomFromText('LINESTRING(1 2, 2 2, 0 0)')) as dump1, 
ST_DumpPoints(ST_GeomFromText('LINESTRING(0 1, 2 2, 3 0)')) as dump2) as subq;
```

Result:

> "POINT(2 2)"

Query is dumping the vertices of the linestrings into points and collects them into multipoints, and finally finds the intersections of the multipoints.

Comment: Great! That helped me a lot.

With your help, I got my query finished.
It may not be perfect and the query runs long. But the result is as expect. See my Answer for the query

Answer (score 1):

This one gives you all the points that occur more than once in the linestrings.

```
BEGIN;

CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE test (
    id serial,
    wkb_geometry geometry(LINESTRING, 4326)
)
ON COMMIT DROP;

INSERT INTO test(wkb_geometry) VALUES
    (ST_GeomFromText('LINESTRING(1 2, 2 2, 0 0)', 4326)),
    (ST_GeomFromText('LINESTRING(0 1, 2 2, 3 0)', 4326));

SELECT ST_AsText((dp).geom), COUNT(1)
FROM (
    SELECT (ST_DumpPoints(wkb_geometry)) dp
    FROM test
) a
GROUP BY ST_AsText((dp).geom)
HAVING COUNT(1) > 1;

COMMIT;
```

Comment: I think that is not, what I am searching for. 

I want to compare 2 linestrings and return the points which exist on both linestrings. I don't want to count any points over all recordsets.

Comment: It is not far from what you want. Just edit the subquery so that it dumps only your two input linestrings into points instead of the whole table.

Comment: You can put those two linestrings into the table. This solution would work for any number of lines.

Answer (score 1):

With the help of user30184, I was able to create my query.
Here it is:

> WITH Data AS(
>
> > SELECT  a.id as ID1, 
> >             b.id as ID2, 
> >             a.way as Geom1, 
> >             b.way as Geom2 
> >         FROM ways AS a
> >         JOIN ways AS b 
> >         ON not(ST_Equals(a.way, b.way))
>
> )
>
> SELECT ID1, ID2, 
>    ST_ASTEXT(ST_Intersection(subq.g1,subq.g2)) AS Intersection, 
>   ST_LineLocatePoint(Geom1, ST_Intersection(subq.g1,subq.g2)) AS Geom1Percent,
>   ST_LineLocatePoint(Geom2, ST_Intersection(subq.g1,subq.g2)) AS Geom2Percent,
>   ST_GEOMETRYTYPE(Geom1) FROM Data,
>
> (
>
> > SELECT ST_Collect(dump1.geom) AS g1, ST_Collect(dump2.geom) AS g2 
> >         FROM 
> >             Data,
> >             ST_DumpPoints(Geom1) as dump1,
> >             ST_DumpPoints(Geom2) as dump2
>
> ) AS subq
>
> WHERE ST_INTERSECTS(subq.g1, subq.g2)
>
> AND
>
> Concat(ST_GEOMETRYTYPE(Geom1), ST_GEOMETRYTYPE(Geom2)) = 'ST_LineStringST_LineString'

That query may not be very good at performance, but gives the result I expect.